# Using fingerprint reader for HP ProBook 138a:003f Validity Sensors

Tags: 16.04, fingerprint-reader

I am using ubuntu 16.04 on HP ProBook 440 G3. It has a finger print reader. `lsusb` shows this following driver

`Bus 001 Device 004: ID 138a:003f Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS495 Fingerprint Reader`

But `Fingerprint GUI` or `Fprint` shows no driver , as expected because `138a:003f` is not in their supported list.
So how can I use the fingerprint reader with ubuntu?

Comment: This guy managed to get it working:
https://balintbanyasz.wordpress.com/2015/03/27/get-validity-vfs-495-fingerprint-reader-working-in-ubuntu-14-04/ I have not tested it on my machine though (work pc, not suitable for tests!)

Comment: @FrancescoTocci I have tried this already. It didn't work instead it corrupted my whole os and I had to reinstall.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal yes see answer. The above guide really works fine but it has some problems so see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/924475/174392) instead.

Answer (score 3):

Instead, use the link below because you might have wrong repos.
I tried it and it is working for me.

[GUI FINGERPRINT SCANNER](https://ubuntuquery.blogspot.com/2017/11/how-to-setup-fingerprint-lock-in-ubuntu.html)

As long as your laptop has a scanner, the above method should work

You can also try [this method](https://balintbanyasz.wordpress.com/2015/03/27/get-validity-vfs-495-fingerprint-reader-working-in-ubuntu-14-04/)

Install proprietary Validity driver via terminal as below.

Download the `.tar` file from [here on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByzOR23A8tIANmRqN1VjQWNhdTQ/view?usp=sharing) and `cd` to the directory where it was saved, then run these commands:

```
tar xf vfs495.tar
cd vfs495
sudo apt-get install alien
sudo alien Validity-Sensor-Setup-4.5-118.00.x86_64.rpm
sudo dpkg -i validity-sensor-setup_4.5-119_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0
sudo ln /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so /usr/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8
sudo apt-get install libcrypto++-dev
sudo ln /usr/lib/libcryptopp.so.9 /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
```

Compile and install libfprint

```
mkdir libfprint
cd libfprint
rpm2cpio ../libfprint-0.0.6-18.20.1.src.rpm | cpio -i --make-directories
tar xf libfprint-0.0.6.tar.bz2
cp ../libfprint-validity.patch ./libfprint-validity.patch
cd libfprint-0.0.6/
patch -p1 < ../libfprint-validity.patch
sudo apt-get install libusb-dev libcrypto++-dev libssl-dev libglib2.0-dev libmagickcore-dev checkinstall
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo checkinstall -install=no make install
sudo dpkg -i libfprint_0.0.6-1_amd64.deb
```

Compile and install fprint_demo

```
cd ../..
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
tar xf fprint_demo-0.4.tar.bz2
cd fprint_demo-0.4
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo checkinstall -install=no make install
sudo dpkg -i fprint-demo_0.4-1_amd64.deb
```

Finally, enroll a finger

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vcsFPServiceDaemon start
sudo fprint_demo
```

This pop-up should appear

[image: thumbnail]

Enroll your right index finger.

You should now be good to go

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/934065)

Comment: Got it. It's on now

Answer (score 1):

You can install the driver from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByzOR23A8tIANmRqN1VjQWNhdTQ/view?usp=sharing). It's an rpm package so you'd need to use `alien` and you should also need to install other packages. Refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/924475/174392) for a guide.