# Using Fingerprint reader in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, login, fingerprint-reader

I have a Dell laptop with fingerprint reader inbuilt. I just ran `lsusb` on terminal and got the following result:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 138a:0011 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05ca:1820 Ricoh Co., Ltd Integrated Webcam
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21bc Broadcom Corp. BCM2070 Bluetooth 2.1 + EDR
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Is it possible to use fingerprint scanning instead of traditional login with 16.04 and Unity ? Thanks.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need the `fingerprint-gui` package, its installation is described at [Fingerprint GUI launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fingerprint-gui) page and reproduced below:

1. Add PP and install `fingerprint-gui` and other required packages

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fingerprint/fingerprint-gui
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install libbsapi policykit-1-fingerprint-gui fingerprint-gui
   ```
2. Log out of your session and log back in.
3. Launch “Fingerprint GUI” and enrol your fingerprints.

Please note: I've used fingerprint readers on various laptops before, they are not very reliable so make sure you don't configure it to be the only source of authentication. It's best to add it on top of passwords as well or you may get locked out at some point.

Comment: fails on Yoga 720

Comment: fails on Thinkpad series

Comment: Works like a charm on old DigitalPersona 4000B!!! Also works not using GUI version: https://askubuntu.com/a/1082465/139248

Comment: My fingerprint reader on a Dell Latitude 7300 with Ubuntu 19.10 currently doesn't seem to be supported. However, I filed a driver request issue at: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/issues?label_name=Driver+Request . Also consider some efforts to get security devices working on Dell laptops: https://github.com/jacekkow/controlvault2-nfc-enable

Comment: @AkhilSurapuram it work OK on Lenovo ThinkPad T430s

Comment: I am using L480 and it is not working @MatějKříž

Comment: it says not devices found

Comment: E: Unable to locate package policykit-1-fingerprint-gui
E: Unable to locate package fingerprint-gui

on Acer Swift3

Answer (score 5):

For fingerprint reader `138a:003f` `VFS 495` this was not sufficient. Many other things had to be installed in certain ways. Refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/924475/174392) for a full guide.

Working on 16.04 on HP Probook 450

Comment: Instead of only linking to another answer it would have been better to flag the question as duplicate of the other question on which you answered.

Comment: suit yourself. It came to my mind but well this question was here first. I dunno. Also make sure that the hardware is exactly identical in both questions.