# How do I get fingerprint working?

Tags: gnome, login, dell, ubuntu-gnome, fingerprint-reader

I have 16.04 LTS Ubuntu Grub (Dell Latitude E7440, swipe sensor)
I don't have any options to use fingerprint in Settings>Accounts
I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/872175/using-fingerprint-reader-in-16-04/872187#872187) guide, but Fingerprint GUI doesn't detect my reader.

`lsusb` gets me: `Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:5801 Broadcom Corp. BCM5880 Secure Applications Processor with fingerprint swipe sensor`

Screenshots of Fingerprint GUI [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrezO.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XQYF.png)