# fingerprint-gui and 18.04 packaging issue

Tags: 18.04, fingerprint-reader

I recently set up a new laptop on 18.04 and am trying to get the fingerprint reader working. I've done it before but fingerprint-gui seems to be broken on 18.04. I roughly followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/872175/using-fingerprint-reader-in-16-04) but got errors from apt-get

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fingerprint-gui : Depends: libqca2-plugin-ossl but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

but upon further research that particular package has been replaced by "libqca2-plugins". I've since installed everything by hand, and fingerprint-gui appears to work, so "libqca2-plugins" appears to be a drop-in replacement.

Am I right in thinking this is simply a packaging issue with fingerprint-reader? Or should that replacement have been automatically detected? Where would I report this?

Comment: I've emailed the package contact listed on the fingerprint-gui launchpad page. Still interested that the package that superseded libqca2-plugin-ossl didn't fulfill that dependency, and that this wasn't picked up in the Bionic beta at all (fingerprint-gui did have a release for it)

Answer (score 1):

Since the original poster didn't provide an answer after he figured it out for himself, here's mine (confirmed to work on 18.04 Bionic Beaver btw):

Basically, you just need to follow the instructions on this answer here ( [Using Fingerprint reader in 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/872175/using-fingerprint-reader-in-16-04/872187#872187)) EXCEPT you need to switch out `libbsapi` with `libqca2-plugins` on the third and final `sudo apt install` line.

Also, unlike Windows 10, swiping your fingerprint at the unlock/login screen needs to be followed by pressing the "Enter" key to manually trigger the unlock (somewhat annoying but still way better than inputting a text-based password everytime), but that's not relevant to this question, just sometime to be aware of for users coming to Ubuntu from Windows.

Comment: That wasn't really my question, I had already worked around the packaging issue, just didn't know the correct people to ask to get it fixed. Eventually got ahold of the package maintainer and he fixed the dependency issue.