# Missing options in settings screens but they appear when searched for

Tags: settings, fingerprint-reader, display-rotation

Recently installed 18.10 on my HP Elitebook 840 G2 after windows decided to stop logging me in (nothing of value lost) Two teething issues

Despite the Fingerprint reader being detected in lsusb I have no option to enroll but when searching for Fingerprint the user's box appears

Am I missing parts of the install or are there options I haven't enabled?

Comment: Can you please edit this to include only one question, and if necessary, ask a second (or third) question separately? "How do I configure a fingerprint reader" and "How do I configure screen orientation" (after searching for similar questions)

Comment: My only issue now is that the option to enroll a fingerprint isn't there.

Comment: Have a look at the [answers to this related question about fingerprint readers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/872175/using-fingerprint-reader-in-16-04) and see if that helps. If it does, this question may be a duplicate.