# Finger-print reader: No devices found

Tags: fingerprint-reader

I recently installed ubuntu 16.04 in my asus vivobook flip 14 tp410uar notebook which has an built-in finger-print reader. According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/872175/using-fingerprint-reader-in-16-04) Q/A I installed `fingerprint-gui`. But after launching the software it says

> **No Devices Found!**

What to do now? I have tried other ways like installing `fprint-demo`. which also says the same thing. How can I detect my finger-print sensor?

[image of the `fingerprint-gui` window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrJdk.png)

---

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f3:2672 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5a03 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Not all fingerprint sensors are supported by linux. You can check what specific sensor you have by looking into `lsusb` output and try to search if some solution exist.

Comment: Most likely `04f3:2672 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ` is your sensor. As far as I know, it's not supported yet.

Comment: It seems like most modern readers aren't supported because: 1. there's not a lot of developer interest and 2. the companies providing the readers don't want to provide OSS drivers/modules as they consider it a possible vector to expose weaknesses in their designs. I've got a Quanta Computer reader in my notebook which will probably just be a decoration for years to come.

Comment: Gain more information with `sudo lshw`, and read `man lshw` for more options.

Comment: Even I am facing this same issue in lenovo ThinkPad series