# How to use 27c6:538d Goodix FingerPrint (Dell Inspiron 5490) (Dell Vostro 5590)?

Tags: dell, inspiron, fingerprint-reader, dell-vostro

I can see this in lsusb[image]
but cannot find option to use it in users option in setting

Comment: See https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/No-driver-for-fingerprint-scanner-Goodix-GF3208-on-Linux/m-p/6242579 which was the first answer found by a web search on _Goodix FingerPrint 27c6:538d  Linux_

Comment: @K7AAY that thread talks about device 27c6:5301 . But in my case device is different and also lsusb is able to show that name of device.

Comment: I'm in the same boat here with an Inspiron 5493. `lsusb` shows the device as a Goodix fingerprint scanner. However, `lshw | grep -a10 -i goodix` notes that this device is "UNCLAIMED". Could this mean that there is no driver for the fingerprint scanner even though it's identified and shown in `lsusb`?

Comment: @VikasKumar: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/872175/using-fingerprint-reader-in-16-04

Comment: @ElderGeek nope

Comment: @user00001 no, not yet

Comment: @VikasKumar Which of the answers to https://askubuntu.com/questions/872175/using-fingerprint-reader-in-16-04 did you try? What were your results? Please [edit] this information into your question. Thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 6):

It seems these Dell laptops are certified and they have similar Goodix fingerpint readers:
https://certification.ubuntu.com/catalog/component/27c6:538c
It's worth trying the 4.15 oem kernel.
It didn't work for me on a 5.4 oem kernel.

I read on the Goodix forum they do not plan to open source drivers but are working with Dell to provide drivers.
Let's hope it will be open sourced.

It's best to get involved in the fprint development website.
Here is the issue for your hardware:

https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/-/issues/196

hope that helps.

[UPDATE] It works for my device with the new proprietary drivers from Goodix.

You can do the following:

```
sudo sh -c 'cat > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-dell.list << EOF
deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ focal-dell public
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ focal-dell public

deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ focal-oem public
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ focal-oem public

deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ focal-somerville public
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ focal-somerville public

deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ focal-somerville-melisa public
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates focal-somerville-melisa public
EOF'
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F9FDA6BED73CDC22
sudo apt update -qq

sudo apt install oem-somerville-melisa-meta libfprint-2-tod1-goodix oem-somerville-meta tlp-config -y
```

I needed a reboot to have the fingerprint scanner working:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 27c6:538c Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Fingerprint Reader
```

You may need to run :

```
sudo pam-auth-update
```

to enable fingerprint for logging in (make sure there is a star).
Work continues on open source drivers too, hopefully these drivers help for reverse engineering.

Anyone knows how to unlock the keyring too? That doesn't seem to happen currently when logging in with fingerprint...

Comment: Glad that it worked for you, but your hardware is different from the one in the question. In this answer you have `27c6:538c`, whereas the questioner (and myself) have `27c6:538d` (Note the final letter). Do you have any idea if anything similar is possible for the fingerprint module in the question?

Comment: hi, did you try it? It's likely that a driver supports multiple id's. You can try and look in the package for your id, or even try to change or add it in the driver, but why not just try it?

Comment: yes I tried it, but it's not detected, when I run fprind-enroll I get no device found

Comment: I grepped the source, your ID is not in there. You could try to recompile with your id and see what happens : git clone git://git.launchpad.net/~oem-solutions-engineers/libfprint-2-tod1-goodix/+git/libfprint-2-tod1-goodix. Otherwise, file a bug (like this one https://bugs.launchpad.net/usbutils/+bug/1721909 ) and use this website/ticket : https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/-/issues/196 to track it. The main issue is that the vendor does not supply info to develop, but people try. You can see what role you can play that best fits your competence. Any help is appreciated!