# Fingerprint access to Dell Vastro 3580

Tags: fingerprint-reader

I have been using Ubuntu since last week.

I have a Dell Vastro laptop which has access to LOGIN with FINGERPRINT.

How could I access this using this Ubuntu.

Comment: Please show output of `lsusb`, it will show the id of the fingerprint device on your laptop. I am facing the same problem on a different laptop here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182758/how-to-use-27c6538d-goodix-fingerprint-dell-inspiron-5490