# Looking for Linux driver for Goodix fingerprint reader 27c6:538d (on Dell Inspiron 7506 2-in-1)

Tags: drivers, dell, inspiron, fingerprint-reader

I am looking for the Linux driver of my fingerprint Goodix 27c6:538d, on my laptop Dell Inspiron 7506 2-in-1, with Ubuntu 20.04.

I followed [this method](https://askubuntu.com/a/1226010/1146790) but it doesn't solve the problem, the fingerprint login option still doesn't appear in Ubuntu Settings \ Users.

Command `cat /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libfprint-2-tod1-goodix.rules` returns :

```
# Goodix Fingerprint Sensor
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="27c6", ATTRS{idProduct}=="538c", ATTRS{dev}=="*", TEST=="power/control", ATTR{power/control}="auto", MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="27c6", ATTRS{idProduct}=="538c", ENV{LIBFPRINT_DRIVER}="Goodix Fingerprint Sensor" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="27c6", ATTRS{idProduct}=="533c", ATTRS{dev}=="*", TEST=="power/control", ATTR{power/control}="auto", MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="27c6", ATTRS{idProduct}=="533c", ENV{LIBFPRINT_DRIVER}="Goodix Fingerprint Sensor"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="27c6", ATTRS{idProduct}=="530c", ATTRS{dev}=="*", TEST=="power/control", ATTR{power/control}="auto", MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="27c6", ATTRS{idProduct}=="530c", ENV{LIBFPRINT_DRIVER}="Goodix Fingerprint Sensor"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="27c6", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5840", ATTRS{dev}=="*", TEST=="power/control", ATTR{power/control}="auto", MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="27c6", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5840", ENV{LIBFPRINT_DRIVER}="Goodix Fingerprint Sensor"
```

I notice that command `lsusb` returns a different version of fingerprint reader : 27c6:538d, not listed in the list mentioned above.

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 27c6:538d Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. FingerPrint
```

I am wondering about something. Maybe `27c6:538d` is not very different from `538c`, so maybe the 538c driver can be used for my 538d device? Or maybe it just needs small modifications that can be done manually?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 4):

I don't think a driver for `27c6:538d` is available yet. A [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libfprint/+bug/1879247) has already been filed in the libfprint package for the same. And unfortunately it may not be as easy as modifying `538c`.