# sudo unable to resolve host and sh: 1: cannot create /tmp/vcsSemKey_ServiceId: Permission denied

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo

This just happened when I wanted to install some new software.
I'm running 16.04 LTS on a HP.

I don't know if this is relevant, but I was recently trying to enable the fingerprint reader on the machine using this [guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/385372/vfs-495-finger-print-reader-not-working-in-ubuntu/924475#924475) but I didn't finish it as some of the packages refused to build. I didn't do any authentication modifications inside the common-auth file.

The last line is repeated continuously and I have to kill the terminal every time I try using `sudo`.

```
chris@chris:~$ sudo -s
sudo: unable to resolve host
[sudo] password for chris: sh: 1: cannot create /tmp/vcsSemKey_ServiceId: Permission denied

sh: 1: cannot create /tmp/vcsSemKey_ServiceId: Permission denied
sh: 1: cannot create /tmp/vcsSemKey_ServiceId: Permission denied
```

[image: terminal]

Comment: What is the output of `grep "vcsSemKey_ServiceId" ~/.bashrc`? if you are using `bash` as your shell. for the "sudo unable to resolve host" see [this Q](https://askubuntu.com/q/59458/283843)

Comment: It doesn't give any output. Thanks for the other

Comment: Please [edit] your question with details about your attempt to enable the fingerprint reader. Was it anything like [this](https://balintbanyasz.wordpress.com/2015/03/27/get-validity-vfs-495-fingerprint-reader-working-in-ubuntu-14-04/)?

Comment: Added information about the fingerprint installation @steeldriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, I fixed it by uninstalling the packages relating to Fingerprint Scanner using Synaptic Package manager, now my terminal works fine. 
Idk if I'm being naive here :/ I'm new to the Linux.

Comment: Thanks alot. I guess I'm stupid for not having tried that. I've just installed synaptic, completely removed the packages and that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you changed your hostname at some point after installation.

First, check the following exists in `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.1.1 chris
```

If it doesn't, add it.

Then make sure `/etc/hostname` contains:

```
chris
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I had recently changed my username and my hosts file wasn't changed. I think this fix will work but only after I get my sudo working first.

Comment: You can boot in to recovery mode if sudo doesn't work.

Comment: I've been trying that but I get stuck. I try to run ``apt-get install --reinstall sudo`` but it won't work because of internet connection. When I try to connect to wifi network using ifconfig and iwconfig and rerun the command again it still doesn't work

Comment: Just adding that I have tried reinstalling sudo, fixing packages, and also manually changing the permissions of the file specified in the error all while in recovery mode but I still have the same error. I might sadly have to reinstall my os.