# Fingerprint scanner worked in 14.04 but NOT in 18.04 (shows no device found)

Tags: 14.04, drivers, 18.04, scanner

I had working fingerprint reader in 14.04. But now in 18.04 Ubuntu bionic beaver, Fingerprint GUI and fingerprint demo >> both of them shows No device found.

I am using Dell latitude 3450 Notebook with fps preinstalled.

Fingerprint GUI shows ATTACHED DEVICES :

Validity Sensors, Inc. (0x138a) VFS495 Fingerprint Reader (0x3f)

But doesn't recognise it.

I have tried "fingerprint-gui and 18.04 packaging issue" guide but results are still same

Please HELP !! 
I am not pro at Ubuntu 
But I am willing to step up for UBUNTU

Answer (score 0):

for 14.04 one needed to follow detailed instructions;

https://balintbanyasz.wordpress.com/2015/03/27/get-validity-vfs-495-fingerprint-reader-working-in-ubuntu-14-04/

that included downloading rpm packages and converting them with alien;

this post from 2017 [VFS 495 finger print reader not working in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/385372/vfs-495-finger-print-reader-not-working-in-ubuntu) updated the above link with updated links; you need to be happy working with terminal commands and to be exact in each step; do you have any friends who work on linux to help you?